# GroupBy() using equality and an object property

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to groups a List of Object depending from

```
1) his Equality (implemented with IEquatable)
2) another Property `bucketNo`.
```

Both conditions.

In the code below I'm trying to do that ...but as I iterate through all the elements of the group:

```
  result[i].Add(children.Key); // doesn't compile
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

```
  List<Part> _buckets = { new Part("001"), new Part("002") ...} , 
  var childrens = _buckets.GroupBy(part => new { part, part.bucketNo });
  var result = new List<List<Part>>();

  foreach (var children in childrens)
  {
       for (var i = 0; i < children.Count(); i++)
       {
            if (result.Count() <= i) result.Add(new List<Part>());
                     result[i].Add(children.Key); // doesn't compile here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding the values from `children` instead of the `Part` in the key `result[i].Add(children[i])`?

Comment: or perhaps `result[i].Add( children[i].Key )`?

Comment: @GregOgle There is no `Key` in `children[i]` because it's just a `Part`.  The other option is `results[i].Add(children.Key.part)` to get the `Part` out of the anonymous class.

Comment: Use a WHERE :  _buckets.Where(x => x.abc == 123).GroupBy(part => new { part, part.bucketNo });

Comment: `results[i].Add(children.Value)` not `Key`